# Authlogic: turn off uniqueness constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

We've been happily running Authlogic for our app for a while. Now, however, we would like to turn off the uniqueness constraint on emails when creating users. Is there a simple way to do this?

I was hoping for something like:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|  
    c.validate_uniqueness_of_email_field = false # This doesn't work  
end
```

What is the exact directive to place within the block to turn off the uniqueness constraint?

Many thanks for your help.

- Shailen Tuli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.validates_uniqueness_of_email_field_options :if => lambda { false }
end
```

Or:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.validates_uniqueness_of_email_field_options :on => []
end
```

Basically the block is treated as a Rails [validator](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates). Unfortunately the value `false` does not work here, nor does the block `{ false }`.

Comment: Many thanks, the first solution you suggested worked like a charm. Very helpful. - Shailen